# How does the Phalanx Soldier ability work with 2 handed weapons and power attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature, fighter, archetype

The [Phalanx Soldier archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo---fighter-archetypes/phalanx-soldier) for fighters gains the following ability

> At 3rd level, when a phalanx soldier wields a shield, he can use any polearm or spear of his size as a one-handed weapon.

When using a [two handed weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#simple-two-handed) you gain an increase in damage from str (if you follow the link, the info is much further down)

> Two hands are required to use a two-handed melee weapon effectively. Apply 1-1/2 times the character's Strength bonus to damage rolls for melee attacks with such a weapon

And [power attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat---final)

> You can choose to take a –1 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a +2 bonus on all melee damage rolls. This bonus to damage is increased by half (+50%) if you are making an attack with a two-handed weapon, a one handed weapon using two hands

So what happens, does the archetype ability allow you to benefit from the extra damage for a 2-handed weapon, or because its not being used in 2-hands you dont?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They would not get the extra fifty percent Str bonus, nor any of the other benefits tied to wielding the weapon with two hands, as you are not. The Two Handed Weapon property means that this weapon usually requires two hands to wield. It is the actual act of wielding a non-light weapon two handed that gives the extra potency behind the swing.

What this Phalanx Fighting (Ex) feature does allow you to do is to have a halberd, longspear, naginata, or what ever your choice of pole arm is in one hand and a spiked shield in the other. Not only does this let you engage at one or two squares away with melee, you cover that much area of attacks of opportunity. This, combined with your ability to shield allies with you features and perhaps teamwork feats, lets you play the sort of defensive fighter that a million Persian can't get passed a scant fifteen score of.

Comment: I figured that it would not get the bonus, but I had nothing to back that up, so thank you